# HttpClient request set Attribute question

Tags: java, parameters, attributes, httpclient

I play for a while (couple of weeks) with this HttpClient lib.
I want somehow to set Attribute to the request. Not parameter but Attribute. In my servlet I want to use Integer inte = (Integer)request.getAttribute("obj");

I have no idea what i miss. i try this.

```
NameValuePair[] pair = new NameValuePair[1];
pair[0] = new NameValuePair();
pair[0].setName("aloha");
pair[0].setValue("value");
```

but this set parameters not attributes..
I also use this because this is only one object who have method that accept string and object. Still not resolved.

```
HttpClientParams clParam = new HttpClientParams();
clParam.setParameter("obj", new Integer(24405));
method.setParams(clParam);
```

Please give me some clue....
Thx.

Comment: What library & language? What do you mean by set Attribute? Also, please don't use "?!?!?!?!?!?" in your title, it doesn't help anyone.

Comment: I assume it's Java since he has a servlet

Comment: @Brian - I think so, since those class names align with Java, and specifically the Apache HTTP-Client library.

Comment: Thanks. I forget that forms in HTML cant only accept text. Cant accept objects. Attributes is set on the server side so servlets can use it. Got it. thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe that you have misunderstood the purpose of the [setAttribute/getAttribute](http://java.sun.com/products/servlet/2.2/javadoc/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#setAttribute(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object)) methods.  The data placed into the request for retrieval by "getAttribute" can only be set with the setAttribute call on the server.  The client cannot force values to be set there, as the only way to pass parameters from the client to the server is via parameters (or some sort of other structure inside of a POST request).

getAttribute/setAttribute are really used for passing information between pieces of server code when using [RequestDispatcher](http://java.sun.com/products/servlet/2.2/javadoc/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html).

Answer (score 0):

From the [servlet request](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/1.4/docs/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getAttribute%28java.lang.String%29) API

> Attributes can be set two ways. The
>   servlet container may set attributes
>   to make available custom information
>   about a request. For example, for
>   requests made using HTTPS, the
>   attribute
>   javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate
>   can be used to retrieve information on
>   the certificate of the client.
>   Attributes can also be set
>   programatically using
>   setAttribute(java.lang.String,
>   java.lang.Object). This allows
>   information to be embedded into a
>   request before a RequestDispatcher
>   call.

Do you actually mean attribute ? Do you perhaps want to set a *parameter* or an *HTTP header* from the client ?